# injector error in angularjs module

Tags: angularjs

This is html page and and module is signhtml why I am getting injector error with this script

> Reseller Login
>
> ```
>     <!-- EXTERNAL CSS -->
>     <link href="styles/open_sans.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
>     <link href="styles/style_v2_optimized.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
>
>
>     <script>
>         window.DOM = {get: function (id) {
>                 return document.getElementById(id)
>             }};
>     </script>
> </head>
> <body class="cp"  id="signin" data-custom-page data-off-canvas-nav data-ng-controller="signinCtrl" data-ng-init="login()">
>     <div id="preload_images"></div>
>
>     <input type="hidden" id="goto_uri" value="">
>     <input type="hidden" id="goto_app" value="">
>     <!-- Do not remove msg_code as it is needed for automated testing - msg_code:[]  -->
>     <div id="login-wrapper" class="group has-pw-reset" style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible;">
>         <div class="wrapper">
>             <div id="notify">
>                 <noscript>
>                 &lt;div class="error-notice"&gt;
>                 &lt;img src="images/notice-error.png" alt="Error" align="left"/&gt;
>                 JavaScript is disabled in your browser.
>                 For Webresellers to function properly, you must enable JavaScript.
>                 If you do not enable JavaScript, certain features in cPanel will not function correctly.
>                 &lt;/div&gt;
>                 </noscript>
>
>                 <div id="login-status" class="success-notice" ng-show="signedinsuccessfully == true">
>                     <div class="content-wrapper">
>                         <div id="login-detail">
>                             <div id="login-status-icon-container"><span
> ```
>
> class="login-status-icon">
>                                   Logged in successfully.Redirecting to panel....
>                               
>                           
>                       
>                       
>                           
>                               
>                                   
>                                   The login is invalid.
>                               
>                           
>                       
>                       
>                           
>                               
>                                   
>                                   The reseller id is not active.
>                               
>                           
>                       
>                       
>                           
>                               
>                                   
>                                   Authenticating.....
>
> ```
>             <div id="content-container">
>                 <div id="login-container">
>
>                     <div id="login-sub-container">
>                         <div id="login-sub-header">
>                             <img class="main-logo" src="../images/logo.png" alt="logo">
>                         </div>
>                         <div id="login-sub">
>                             <div id="clickthrough_form" style="visibility:hidden">
>                                 <form action="javascript:void(0)">
>                                     <div class="notices"></div>
>                                     <button type="submit" class="clickthrough-cont-btn">Continue</button>
>                                 </form>
>                             </div>
>                             <div id="forms">
>                                 <form novalidate="" id="login_form" ng-submit="login()" style="visibility:">
>                                     <div class="input-req-login"><label for="username">Reseller
> ```
>
> Id
>                                           
>                                               
>                                           
>                                           Password
>                                           
>                                               
>                                           
>                                           
>                                               
>                                                   Sign in
>
> ```
>                                         <div class="reset-pw">
>                                             <a href="#/account/forgot-password">Forgot your password?</a>
>                                         </div>
>                                     </div>
>                                     <div class="clear" id="push"></div>
>                                 </form>
>                                 <!--CLOSE forms -->
>                             </div>
>                             <!--CLOSE login-sub -->
>                         </div>
>
>                    <!--CLOSE wrapper -->
>                     </div>
>                     <!--CLOSE login-sub-container -->
>                 </div>
>                 <!--CLOSE login-container -->
>             </div>
>
>
>         </div>
>         <!--Close login-wrapper -->
>     </div>
>
>     <script src="../js/angular/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
>     <!--<script src="../js/angular/1.2.7/angular-resource.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
>     <script src="../js/angular/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
>     <script src="../js/angular/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
>     <script src="scripts/sgnscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
>     <script type="text/javascript">var currentip = '56.121.99.78';</script>
>     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://l2.io/ip.js?var=currentip"></script>
>
>
>
>     <style>
>         @media (min-width: 481px) {
>             #select_user_form {
>                 width: px;
>             }
>         }
>     </style>
>     <div class="copyright">Copyright©&nbsp;2016 Simpact E-Soft Pvt. Ltd..</div>
>
> </body></html>
> ```

```
var signApp = angular.module('logApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);

signApp.controller('signinCtrl',function ($scope, $http, $filter, $uibModal) {
    // sign in panel start
            console.log('widisn');
    $scope.credentials = {username: '', password: ''};  
    $scope.signedinsuccessfully = false;
    $scope.invalidusernamepwd = false;
    $scope.notactive = false;
    $scope.signingin = false;
    $scope.login = function () {
        if (readCookie('loginsignature') != null) {
            if ($scope.signingin == false || $scope.signedinsuccessfully == false) {
                $scope.signedinsuccessfully = false;
                $scope.invalidusernamepwd = false;
                $scope.notactive = false;
                $scope.signingin = true;
                $http.post('logs.php', {fn: 'login', username: $scope.credentials.username, password: $scope.credentials.password, ip: currentip}).then
                        (function (response) {
                            console.log(response);
                            if (response.data.response == 1) {
                                $scope.signingin = false;
                                var jobj = response.data.data;
                                var srv = response.data.services;
                                if (jobj[0].response == 0) {
                                    $scope.invalidusernamepwd = true;
                                    $scope.notactive = false;
                                } else if (jobj[0].response == 2) {
                                    $scope.invalidusernamepwd = false;
                                    $scope.notactive = true;
                                } else {
                                    $scope.signedinsuccessfully = true;
                                    $scope.credentials.username = '';
                                    $scope.credentials.password = '';
                                    eraseCookie('loginsignature');
                                    eraseCookie('resellername');
                                    eraseCookie('domainname');
                                    eraseCookie('username');
                                    eraseCookie('clients');
                                    eraseCookie('credit');
                                    eraseCookie('debit');
                                    eraseCookie('balance');
                                    eraseCookie('sales');
                                    eraseCookie('lastwithdrawal');
                                    eraseCookie('services');
                                    createCookie('loginsignature', jobj[0].signature, "");
                                    createCookie('resellername', jobj[0].name, "");
                                    createCookie('domainname', jobj[0].domainname, "");
                                    createCookie('username', jobj[0].username, "");
                                    var dbd = response.data.dashboarddata;
                                    createCookie('clients', dbd[0].clients, "");
                                    createCookie('credit', dbd[0].credit, "");
                                    createCookie('debit', dbd[0].debit, "");
                                    createCookie('balance', dbd[0].balance, "");
                                    createCookie('sales', dbd[0].sales, "");
                                    createCookie('lastwithdrawal', dbd[0].lastwithdrawal, "");
                                    createCookie('services', JSON.stringify(srv));
                                    $scope.data.name = readCookie('resellername');
                                    $scope.data.domainname = readCookie('domainname');
                                    $scope.data.username = readCookie('username');
                                    $scope.data.loginsignature = readCookie('loginsignature');

                                    $scope.dashboarddata.clients = dbd[0].clients;
                                    $scope.dashboarddata.credit = dbd[0].credit;
                                    $scope.dashboarddata.debit = dbd[0].debit;
                                    $scope.dashboarddata.balance = dbd[0].balance;
                                    $scope.dashboarddata.sales = dbd[0].sales;
                                    $scope.dashboarddata.lastwithdrawal = dbd[0].lastwithdrawal;

                                    $scope.services.allservices = srv;
//                                    $location.path('/dashboard');
                                }
                            } else
                            {
                                $scope.signingin = false;
                            }
                        }, function (response) {
                            alert('Error login..');
                        });
            }
        } else
        {
            $scope.signedinsuccessfully = false;
            $scope.invalidusernamepwd = false;
            $scope.notactive = false;
            $scope.signingin = true;
            $http.post('logs.php', {fn: 'isloggedin', signature: readCookie('loginsignature'), ip: currentip}).then
                    (function (response) {
                        $scope.signingin = false;
                        console.log(response);
                        if (response.data.response == 1) {
                            var jobj = response.data.data;
                            if (jobj[0].response == 1)
                            {
                                console.log($location.path());
//                                                if ($location.path() == '/account/signin') {
//                                                    $location.path('/dashboard');
//                                                }
                                window.location = '/dashboard';
                            }
                        }
                    }, function (response) {
                        alert('Error checking isloggedin..');
                    });
        }
    }
    // sign in panel end
});
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal, reproducible problem? What is the specific error?

Comment: @user1525591 could you please post your error messag here. i saw $location in your controller. but its not injected into it